# Report using SqL

Tags: sql, oracle

Would like a report created out of 3 tables with the exact output

Users table

```
User id  User name 
1         user1
2         user2
3         user3
```

USER_IN_ROLES table

```
USRINR_USER_ID   USRINR_ROLES_ID

1                        103
3                        104
2                        105
1                        107
2                        108
1                        105
1                        108
```

roles rl

```
Roles ID                 Description
104                      User management
107                      Modify
103                      Debit
105                      General
108                      Audit
```

Relation User id between table 1 & 2 and roles id between 2 & 3

I would like a query that will give an op like this

```
UName   FirstEntitl     Second Entitl
user1   Read only user  Debit
user3   Security admin  User Management
user2    Team           General
user1   Read only user  Modify
user2    Team           Audit
user1   Read only user  General
user1   Read only user  Audit
```

My attempt very basic

```
 select usr.user_name, rl.role_code as firstentitl,
 Case
   When rl.role_code = 'UserManagement' then 'Sec Admin'
   When rl.role_code  = 'ManualModification' then 'BelgiumTax User'
   End as secondEntitileme
from users usr, USER_IN_ROLES uir,  roles rl
where usr.user_id=uir.usinr_user_id 
and rl.role_id=uir.usinr_role_id;
```

So all users who have user managemnt as role( no other roles) will be Security admin A users who have modiy role will be team and if a user doesnt have modify and user managemnt is a read only user

Comment: I think all that is missing is the ELSE condition in your CASE statement

Answer (score 0):

```
rl.role_code as firstentitl,
```

There is no such column existing in the table, if you want that kind of output then need to maintain that in user roles and map the userid to the role and query from the sql.

```
SCOTT@research 02-APR-15> select * from user1;

     USRID UNAME      ROLEDET
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 user1      Read only user
         2 user2      Team
         3 user3      Security admin

SCOTT@research 02-APR-15> select * from usr_roles;

     USRID     ROLEID
---------- ----------
         1        103
         2        104
         3        105

SCOTT@research 02-APR-15> select * from role_det ;

    ROLEID ROLEDET
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       103 user management
       104 modify
       105 debt

SCOTT@research 02-APR-15>  select usr.USRID, usr.roledet as firstentitl,
  2   Case
  3     When rl.roledet = 'user management' then 'Sec Admin'
  4     When rl.roledet  = 'modify' then 'BelgiumTax User'
  5     End as secondEntitileme
  6  from user1 usr, usr_roles uir,  role_det rl
  7  where usr.USRID=uir.USRID
  8  and rl.ROLEID=uir.ROLEID;

UNAME      FIRSTENTITL                              SECONDENTITILEM
---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------
user1      Read only user                           Sec Admin
user2      Team                                     BelgiumTax User
user3      Security admin
```

Comment: --> i need to create the output of the 3rd column in such a way that i get a row in the output for each row in table 2 and i need to get populated it with multiple rows  Read only user or team depending on user name if it has modify or not